# How do I find min and max of index when using group by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I use `time` as index in a Pandas DataFrame.

| time | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 05 01 00:00:00 | JG8oYBAA | 123 |
| 2021 05 01 01:00:00 | JG8oYBAA | 431 |
| 2021 05 01 01:00:00 | pM8SWMrM | 213 |

I can run `df.groupby('id')['value'].min()` to find min value for each id:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| JG8oYBAA | 123 |
| pM8SWMrM | 213 |

But when trying this with the index `df.groupby('id').index.min()` ... I get:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'index'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset the index before performing groupby.

```py
df.reset_index().groupby('id').agg({'value': min, 'time (index)': min})
```